# Stanford's initial assignment not working

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Stanford put out for free a series of videos and handouts for their iPhone programming course.  I've played around with the first assignment, but all I get on the Simulator is a blank screen.  Here's the recipe I followed; what am I missing?

> In Xcode, create a new Window-Based iPhone application.
>   Open the project’s MainWindow.xib file with Interface Builder.
>   Add the following user interface elements to the view:
>
> - a text label
> - an image view
>
> Set the following properties on the text label:
>
> - text value should be “Hello Stanford!” (or something suitably amusing)
> - text alignment should be centered
> - adjust the size to make the text large
>
> Back in Xcode, add an image (.png or .jpg) to your project. You can use the Project > Add to Project... menu to select an image. Note: Be sure to check the “Copy items into desti- nation group’s folder (if needed)” checkbox.
>
> Once your image is in the project, return to MainWindow.xib, select the image view and set the image for the image view that you dragged in previously using the Attributes Inspector.
>   Configure the image view’s “Mode” to be “Aspect Fit”
>
> In Xcode, build and run your project in the simulator.

Been there, done that, but no t-shirt.  Seems to me I'm missing connecting lines in the Interface Builder, but I see nothing in the recipe about that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a link, I'll assume you're talking about [this document](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/assignments/Assignment1A_0.pdf).

Works for me on XCode 3.2.3/Snow Leopard 10.6.4. I created the project as iPhone-only, as opposed to Universal, but it shouldn't make a difference for your purposes.

Try again from scratch, or [take a look at my project here](http://warrenmoore.net/files/StackTest.zip).